# "None saw this coming." - Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: pronouns

I understand I can say No one saw it coming but wonder if it is okay to say "None saw it coming."?

Also, is the punctuation correct in the end of the last statement?

Comment: Why would you think it may not be okay? Can you elaborate? Is it gut feeling alone :) There's no question mark needed there.

Answer (score 1):

To me, None is synonymous with Not One or with Not Any. It follows that None, like One and Any, may be considered respectively singular or plural, depending on context. Your sentence makes sense from all these viewpoints, although Saw is both singular and plural, so we need not debate the verb form, as we might if your example included "none is/are ..." There is no need for a question mark because there is no explicit question in the statement "I ... wonder ..."